# Difficulties with Executing VBA Script every hours

Tags: vba, excel, autorun

I am attempting to have this VBA script (which sends me an Email should a task reach its Due Date) every Hour or so. I looked around at tutorials around and attempted a few examples, but I get a message evertime I attempt to run it.
Would anyone be kind enough to give it a quick look?

Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TaskTracker()
Dim FormulaCell          As Range
Dim FormulaRange    As Range
Dim NotSentMsg      As String
Dim MyMsg           As String
Dim SentMsg         As String
Dim MyLimit         As Double

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

'Equals the MyLimit value it will triger the email
MyLimit = Date


Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("E5:E35")
On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If .Value = MyLimit Then
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    strTO = "fmal@ox.com"
                    strCC = "fs@ox.com"
                    strBCC = ""
                    strSub = "Greetings " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value
                    strBody = "Hi Sir, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "This email is to notify that you need to do your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Regards, Yourself"
                    If sendMail(strTO, strSub, strBody, strCC) = True Then MyMsg = SentMsg
'Call Mail_with_outlook2

 End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description
Call AutoRun
End Sub


Sub AutoRun()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "TaskTracker"
End Sub
```

It is to my understanding that the script should call the AutoRun sub before ending itself. But it doesn't. 
When I attempt to manually run the AutoRun sub itself, it states "Cannot run the macro "*\Task Tracker.clsm'TaskTracker'. The macro may not be available in this workbook, or all macros may be disabled."

Comment: Call the autorun after Next FormulaCell and delete the part ExitMacro: Exit Sub and retry.

Comment: It says Some Error Occurred: 0 when I do so and attempt to run it. After dismissing it, I get the same error message
Oh hey again Kathara :D Look at me attempting to pimp the script hehe

Comment: Calling the Autorun after Next Formula and keeping the Exit Macro now do attempts to run the AutoRun (which wasn't happening before) but I still get the Cannot run the macro "*\Task Tracker.xlsm'TaskTracker' error

The sub is called TraskTracker but the workbook is named Task Tracker, can it be part of the reason why it think it doesn't exist?

The current script is in the Worksheet itself. Should it be placed in the Workbook instead? Should the AutoRun be placed inside a module?

Comment: Yes, hello again!! Ehhm ok, leave the exitMacro. The problem I see is that the call AutoRun is located in the endMacro statement which will only be called if there is an error. The error could be caused because the first sub is not yet finished when you call the autorun and in the autorun you call that sub again. So this might cause and endless loop. If you could call the AutoRun when the other sub has ended, there should not be a problem...

Comment: I once had a similar problem, then I recorded a macro, where I then put in my code. Only then would it be recognized as a macro. Before you try that though try to delete the Private in front of the first sub, see if that makes any difference. :)

Comment: Is it me or is there an `End If` missing?  I can see 3 `IF` only 2 `End If`

Comment: Yes, for the If sendMail. Funny that you didn't get an error for that.......

Comment: Humm weird indeed cause everything works properly before attempting to autorun it :O I sent myself about 20 emails while doing tests :P

I'll check for the suggestion above and see how it goes :)

Comment: The Record Macro trick made it work! :)

Comment: Although everytime it runs (every 10 seconds for testing purpose) if the Email Sent is at "Sent" it switches it to "Not Sent", thus spamming me with the same tasks infinitely.

Is there something in the code that causes this?

Comment: I think I fixed it by changing: 
                If .Value = MyLimit Then
                    MyMsg = NotSentMsg




To                 If .Value = MyLimit Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg

That way, I have to manually set it to Not Sent, the script doesn't change it if the value = date.

Comment: @Fred There is a single-line syntax for `If... Then... Else...`. No `End If` needed.

Comment: @EganWolf Correct, my bad I just noticed 3 If's 2 End If's Should have looked for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything's working properly. Thanks everyone! (Leaving an answer to I can mark this topic as answered) :)

The below code works perfectly for me. As suggested by Kathara, the Call Autorun had to be placed after Next Formula Cell. Furthermore, I had to record a blank Macro, and copy paste the whole code for the loop check to work properly!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TaskTracker()
Dim FormulaCell          As Range
Dim FormulaRange    As Range
Dim NotSentMsg      As String
Dim MyMsg           As String
Dim SentMsg         As String
Dim MyLimit         As Double

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

MyLimit = Date

Set FormulaRange = Range("E5:E35")
On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If .Value = MyLimit Then
                MyMsg = SentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    strTO = "Fr@Aion.com"
                    strCC = ""
                    strBCC = ""
                    strSub = "[Task Manager] Reminder that you need to: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value
                    strBody = "Hello Sir, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "This email is to notify that you that your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value & " with the following note: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & " is nearing its Due Date." & vbNewLine & "It would be wise to complete this task before it expires!" & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Truly yours," & vbNewLine & "Task Manager v1.0"
                    If sendMail(strTO, strSub, strBody, strCC) = True Then MyMsg = SentMsg
'                        Call Mail_with_outlook2
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

Next FormulaCell
Call AutoRun

ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub

Sub AutoRun()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "TaskTracker"
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone for your help!